# how can I determine that works requestLocationUpdates?

Tags: android, gps

I use requestLocationUpdates listener receives data.
how can I determine that works requestLocationUpdates? need a method that will bring back true - if requestLocationUpdates enabled or false if I turned it off (removeUpdates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method. For the `LocationListener` flavor of `requestLocationUpdates()`, it is pretty easy for you to track it yourself:

Step #1: Add a data member to some class, of type `boolean`, named `areLocationUpdatesEnabled`, initially set to `false`.

Step #2: When you call `requestLocationUpdates()`, set `areLocationUpdatesEnabled` to `true`.

Step #3: When you call `removeUpdates()`, set `areLocationUpdatesEnabled` to `false`.

Step #4 (optional): Implement `areLocationUpdatesEnabled()` as a method to return the value of `areLocationUpdatesEnabled`.